# Popup on clicking anywhere on the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Basically I need a functionalty like on this video https://www.loom.com/share/916a457d02d84aa699e1e22c6b5b5879

When I click anywhere, the popup opens on that specifc location, like on that video. Also to activate that click, you need to click +comment button first like on the video

Hope someone can help me

Basically I am stuck, not sure where to start

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Don't just ask us to do your work for you.

Comment: I didn't ask for a code, I just wanted some direction on where to start

Comment: The issue is that you haven't asked any question. You posted a general requirement, plus a link to a video people are required to view, and then asked the Community to solve this (or put you on the path to a solution). This is too broad, and it's not a specific question.

Comment: The work I mentioned was _research_. You need to learn the mechanisms that make such a feature work. They're well covered on SO and elsewhere already. Then come back and ask about your code if you have trouble. Hint: search 'how to create a popup' (a.k.a. "modal dialog").

Answer (score 1):

You have to create block in layout with style `position: absolute;` and hide it by `display: none;`.

In Javascript you should listen click event on the body:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  // here you can get click params by event object
})
```

Now get position of click, set it on styles of block `top: ...px;` and `left: ...px;`. After that set `display: block;` for show this block.

Comment: The OP showed no work, just a requirement. Please don't answer such questions. This really isn't the place for people to post a requirement and have others implement it.

Comment: I didn't ask for a code, I just wanted some direction on where to start

Comment: @SushilThapa - that's not how Stack Overflow works; it's not for general discussion or idea generation. It's for specific programming questions.